# How do I hook up a business modem with 6 ports to a switched network?

Tags: networking, nat, static-ip, modem

I have a small business modem that has 6 ports on it, each being a static IP.

My network has grown however to the point where I have more than 6 devices, so I am moving to use a switch, which has other benefits as well.

Does that make my 6 static IPs redundant? Should I just connect one of them to the switch and NAT everything, or is there a way I can use all 6 IPs?

Comment: Who is the ISP? What equipment did they give you?

Answer (score 1):

You use a proper router, that you own and/or can configure, and assign your public IPs using that and NAT everything else.
The modem should just be a modem at that point.